# Move The Caret Position To The Particular X,y Coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf

How to move my Carete Postion to the particular X,Y coordinates.

Is it Possible to do it.

I have Two Richtextbox And I want to move the 2nd richtextbox Carete position to the 1st richtextbox Y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Point that was clicked on to a pointer into the text

```
 var index = d.GetPositionFromPoint(point, true);
 d.CaretIndex = index;
```

where d is your RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Rect rec1= myrichtextbox1.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
Rect rec2= myrichtextbox2.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);

myrichtextbox2.CaretPosition = myrichtextbox1.GetPositionFromPoint(new Point(rec2.X, rec1.Y), snapToText);
        CommentsEditor.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("your Text");
```

Comment: i am setting the carete position of 2nd richtextbox by getting y coordinates of 1st richtextbox and x coordinates of 2nd richtextbox   so that tha poiner in the 2nd richtextbox moves to the line correspoinding to the 1st richtextbox careteposition